# Flex ant mxmlc command vs exec command

Tags: mxmlc

I am trying to figure out if there is any difference in any aspect of triggering flex compiler from ant file by using ant task 'mxmlc' or OS command 'exec'.

Answer (score 0):

No difference in result.
There are just some other options to flex ant tasks.